# How to turn off text AntiAliasing in IE(6/7/8)(VML)

Tags: internet-explorer, raphael, antialiasing, vml

[image: Map]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZp6L.jpg!

I have a map implemented via Raphael JS, which wraps VML and SVG to support cross web browsers drawing.

Everything looks good except the font in IE(6/7/8)

it seems AntiAliasing is turned on rendering the text in VML, and the text looks unclear and blur,  please is there a way to turn off the AntiAliasing?

Answer (score 0):

To the `SVG` tag, add `shape-rendering = 'crispEdges'`

Does that solve the issue?

You can also try adding `font-smooth : never` to your styles for the SVG.

Comment: I don't have this problem in SVG, I have the problem in VML.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use not `px` in `font-size`. Use `pt` or `%`.
2. You can use `@font-face` with `eot` font format. Custom fonts render without antialiasing.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
         font-family:comic;
         src:url(http://valid_url/some_font_file.eot);
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p style="font-family: comic; font-size: 18pt;">This paragraph uses the font-face 
   rule defined in the above style element. The rule embeds an OpenType file for the 
   Comic Sans font. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) generator to generate `EOT` font file.